# how to use pcre library to match url in c program

Tags: c, regex, pcre, lighttpd

how to match url `/[a-z0-9]/phpmyadmin/` ?
if url matches regex = `/^\/([a-z0-9])+\/phpmyadmin/g`
how to capture groups to char for further operation?

for example, i have this

```
char *url = "/zs0099/phpmyadmin";
```

I want to match it against regex `/^\/([a-z0-9])+\/phpmyadmin/g`
if it matches then

```
char *token = "zs0099"; //(how to get this value to assigned here)
```

Comment: a good search engine is your friend http://www.mitchr.me/SS/exampleCode/AUPG/pcre_example.c.html

Answer (score 0):

quick shot from the hip (but without pcre), bare C ( small state machine )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isMatch( char *url, char *p ) {
    int state= 0;
    while ( *url != 0 ) {
        switch (state) {
            // first state: char must be '/'
            case 0: 
               if (*url != '/') return 0;
               state=1;
               url++;
               break;
            // only characters and numbers are valid, another '/' ends this
            case 1: 
               if (isalpha(*url) || isdigit(*url)) { *p++=*url; url++; break; }
               if (*url == '/') { url++; state=2; break; }
               return 0; // not alhanum nor '/' --> not valid;
               break;
           case 2:
               *p++=0;
               if (strcmp(url, "phpmyadmin")==0) return 1;
               return 0;
           }
   }
   return 0;
}

int main() {
    char part[256];

    char *x1 = "/019sasA/phpmyadmin";
    int matches = isMatch(x1, part);
    printf ("%s, %i --> %s \n", x1, matches , matches ? part : "");

    char *x2 = "/019sasA/phpadmin";
    matches = isMatch(x2, part);
    printf ("%s, %i --> %s \n", x2, matches , matches ? part : "");

    char *x3 = "/019sa,sA/phpmyadmin";
    matches = isMatch(x3, part);
    printf ("%s, %i --> %s \n", x3, matches , matches ? part : "");
}
```

possible issues: 
"//phpmyadmin" is valid (could be easily fixed with one more state, where the first state only accepts isdigit() and isnumber(), no '/')
"/phpmyadmin" is invalid